# Store data according to starting date

Tags: r

I am working with multiple csv files stored in a folder (2488). Each csv contains monthly data from gaugin stations with the format years * months. I want to store all these csv files in a big data frame in which cols are the IDs of the different gaugin stations and the rows the times %Y-%m-%d.

For this purpose, I have list all the files with `list.files`:

```
a <- list.files(pattern="./*.csv",full.names=TRUE)
```

And create a dummy data frame with the final dimensions:

```
gst <- data.frame(NA,1860,2488) # 1860 times - 2488 stations
```

Each csv file starts in a different date. The earliest date found is January 1863, so I created the data frame with 1860 rows from that starting date to June 2017.

I create a sequence of dates to name the rows of `gst`:

```
    s <- paste0(1863,"-01-01")
    e <- paste0(2017,"-12-31")
    ss<- chron(s, format='y-m-d')
    ee<- chron(e, format='y-m-d')
    dates <- seq.dates(ss,ee,by='months')
```

In the following loop, I read each csv file. First I change the initial data frame format: years * months + total column.

```
# Initial format          
            Jan     Feb     Mar    Apr
    1993    NA      0.05    0.05    0.06
    1994    0.18    0.15    0.1     0.19
    1995    0.22    0.23    0.26    0.11
    1996    0.14    0.11    0.1     0.08
    1997    0.12    0.16    0.07    0.05
    1998    0.12    0.07    0.12    0.18
    1999    0.07    0.32    0.14    0.15
    2000    0.13    0.22    0.15    0.1
    2001    0.18    0.09    0.5     0.26
```

to a single column data frame (kk.df) with data stored as:

```
Date      Value
93-01-01  NA
93-02-01  0.05
93-03-01  0.05
93-04-01  0.06
93-05-01  0.05
93-06-01  0.05
93-07-01  0.03
93-08-01  0.03
93-09-01  0.05
93-10-01  0.09
93-11-01  0.04
93-12-01  0.10
```

This is the loop I am working with:

```
for (i in 1:length(a)){

  kk <- read.csv(a[i])
  colnames(kk) <- c(seq(1,12,1),'total') # 12 (months) columns and a total column

  kk.ts <- ts(as.vector(t(as.matrix(kk))),
              start=as.numeric(c(rownames(kk)[1],1)), end= as.numeric(c(rownames(kk)[dim(kk)[1]],12)),frequency=12)

  kk.df <- as.data.frame(kk.ts)
  colnames(kk.df) <- a[[i]]

    a <- paste0(start,"-01-01")
    b <- paste0(end,"-12-31")
    ac<- chron(a, format='y-m-d')
    bc<- chron(b, format='y-m-d')
    times <- seq.dates(ac,bc, by="months")

    rownames(kk.df) <- times


    gst[i,] <- kk.df
}
```

My question is, as I am storing the same number of columns as gaugin stations I have (2488 stations) and each station start at a different Year-month, how can I specify when store each `i` for each station, the row in which it must start?

If `i` = 1 and the first record is in 1993-01-01, I want that column to start at the row of `gst` that corresponds to 1993-01-01 and so on with the rest of the stations.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could incorporate a join in your for loop for that:

```
df  = data.frame(date = seq(Sys.Date(),Sys.Date()+3,by=1))
station1 = data.frame(date = seq(Sys.Date()+2,Sys.Date()+3,by=1),data = c(1,2))
station2 = data.frame(date = seq(Sys.Date()+1,Sys.Date()+2,by=1),data = c(2,3))

df = df %>% left_join(station1) %>% rename(station1=data)
df = df %>% left_join(station2) %>% rename(station2=data)
```

Input:

```
> df
        date
1 2017-07-17
2 2017-07-18
3 2017-07-19
4 2017-07-20
> station1
        date data
1 2017-07-19    1
2 2017-07-20    2
> station2
        date data
1 2017-07-18    2
2 2017-07-19    3
```

Output:

```
> df
        date station1 station2
1 2017-07-17       NA       NA
2 2017-07-18       NA        2
3 2017-07-19        1        3
4 2017-07-20        2       NA
```

Comment: Thank you Florian Maas, while trying the left-join I ended up solving the problem by 'index':  data[rownames(kk.df), colnames(kk.df)[2]] = as.numeric(as.character(kk.df[2][[1]])) This way every gaugin station is stored at the time that matchs the rownames.

Comment: Great that you were able to resolve your issue, glad I could help!